# How is Array#each implemented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm curious about the mechanism of collection and block in Ruby. We can define a class like this:

```
class Foo
    include Enumerable
    def initialize
        @data = []
    end

    def each
        if block_given?
            @data.each { |e| yield(e) }
        else
            Enumerator.new(self, :each)
        end
    end 
end
```

I want to know how `@data.each` can use the block `{ |e| yield(e) }` as the parameter. I searched the implementation of Array#each:

```
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

but this doesn't even seem like a Ruby language implementation. How is `Array#each` implemented in Ruby?

Edit:

It looks like C code traverses the first to final array element and call ruby yield function with the parameter of the traversed array element. But where is the block passed to `rb_ary_each` function?

Comment: It is not implemented in Ruby. It is implemented in C.

Comment: _Something_ has to be implemented outside of Ruby...

Comment: It's not unique to `Array.each` - _any_ method in Ruby can take a block.

Comment: It's trivial to write a pure Ruby implementation if you understand how blocks/`yield` works. That seems to be your actual underlying question; "how do blocks work".

Comment: @joews Yes. I know any method in Ruby can take a block. But I'm wondering how this method can iterate the array. I cannot see how it do it with the C code.

Comment: You can't see how the C code iterates the Ruby array? It's the for loop.

Comment: I think just like in Ruby, the block is passed implicitly in the C code. How exactly that is achieved is beyond my understanding of C.

Comment: The block is not passed. Every Ruby method can accept a block and simply ignore it if not needed. `rb_yield` handles passing of the iterated value to the block. What else would we need?

Comment: It seems that in `rb_ary_each(VALUE array)` the block to be run is not passed in, how would `rb_yield ` know what to perform?

Comment: I may come late to this topic, but I guess that VALUE array is a object/struct instead of an primitive value as int, char, etc. So, what rb_ary_each method is receiving is a pointer to the object/struct of the type VALUE. If that is true (I'm just guessing here for what I know about C) then the block is passed inside the object/struct with the other arguments. If I'm wrong, please, someone correct me! hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple Ruby implementation of an `each`-like method that doesn't rely on the existence of any of Ruby's built-in iterator methods:

```
class List
  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end
  def each
    i = 0
    while i < @arr.length
      yield @arr[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
l = List.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])
l.each {|x| puts x}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

I may come late to this topic, but I guess that VALUE array is a object/struct instead of an primitive value as int, char, etc. So, what rb_ary_each method is receiving is a pointer/reference to the object/struct of the type VALUE. If that is true (I'm just guessing here for what I know about C) then the block is passed inside the object/struct with the remain arguments.

I'm also guessing that another object/struct should exist to hold the block/proc/lambda, so the VALUE object/struct should hold a pointer/reference to the first one.

If I'm wrong, please, someone correct me! Your question are much more related to how C works than Ruby.